# A problem about tangents and areas.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 4x^2 + 4x$, its graph denoted $C$. If for any $x_1 \not = \frac 43$, the tangent of $f(x)$ at the point $P_1(x_1, f(x_1))$ intersects $C$ at another point $P_2(x_2, f(x_2))$, and similarly, the tangent of $f(x)$ at $P_2$ intersects $C$ at another point $P_3(x_3, f(x_3))$. Let $S_1, S_2$ be the area between $C$ and the line segment $P_1P_2, P_2P_3$, respectively. Find the value of $\frac {S_1}{S_2}$.

I wanted to evaluate $S_1$ and $S_2$ directly, and I guess $x_1$ will cancel out at last. But this seems tedious. Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: The answer appears to be $\frac{1}{16}$. I can post the solution if you want, but it involves a lot of algebra, so it would have to be abbreviated. What interests me is that, judging by the expression obtained for $S_1$, this result would appear to be true for *any* cubic, but I'm not sure why that is. If there was a simple reason why, then the proof would be a lot simpler if we established it with $f(x)=x^3$

Comment: In fact the same result does indeed apply to $f(x)=x^3$...

Comment: @DavidQuinn But are there any simpler ways to calculate? I also know that it's $1/16$ (by using $(2,0)$ as $P_1$). By the way, what happens when $x = 4/3$, and, since you said that this result would appear to be true for any cubic, what are the restrictions of $x$ in other cases?

Comment: The value $x=\frac 43$ corresponds to the point of inflection on the graph. The tangent at this point does not intersect with the graph at any other point so this value has to be excluded. Similarly for all other cubics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we will express the curve in parametric form:

Let the point $P_1$ be $(t,t(t-2)^2)$, and let the parameter values at $P_2$ and $P_3$ be $p$ and $q$ respectively.

The equation of the tangent at $P_1$ is

$$y-(t^3-4t^2+4t)=(3t^2-8t+4)(x-t)$$

At $P_2$, $x=p$, so we substitute the coordinates of $P_2(p,p(p-2)^2)$ into this equation and simplify. We are aided by the fact that $(p-t)^2$ must be a factor, and this equation reduces to:
$$p=4-2t$$
From this we can deduce also that $$q=4-2p$$

The area $$S_1=\left|\int^p_t (x^3-4x^2-x(3t^2-8t)+2t^3-4t^2 )dx\right|$$
After **some algebra** and applying the condition $p=4-2t$, this simplifies to $$S_1=\frac{1}{12}(3t-4)^4$$

We can therefore immediately deduce that $$S_2=\frac{1}{12}(3p-4)^4=\frac{1}{12}(3t-4)^4\times 2^4$$

and hence the result $$\frac{S_1}{S_2}=\frac{1}{16}$$

Comment: So what if $f(x)$ is an arbitrary cubic equation? Will this hold?

Comment: It certainly looks that way